# Is it possible to create `null` value without actually using `null`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, null

I wonder if it's possible to create a `null` value  , without actually using `null`

For example:

> `code-without-null`    // null

One trick that I know is to :

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(NaN)) //null
```

**Question:**

What other ways exists to get `null` without using `null` ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why would you need to do this?

Comment: @Turnip Yesterday I was at a meetup and a colleague has asked it , and no one knew.... hence it's only curiosity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS already provides it by definition :

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype)
```

(From Allen:)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could match a not given pattern.

```js
console.log(''.match(/./));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are [many functions which return null](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22returns+null%22+mdn). Feel free to use any of them:

```js
console.log([
  document.parentElement,
  document.querySelector('does not exist'),
  /foo/.exec('')
].every(val => val === null)
);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking :`document.querySelector('does not exist'),` , you never know.... Also won't work in node

Answer (score 1):

The [`String.prototype.match()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return a `null` value if it doesn't find any matches.

Example taken from linked docs:

```
var str = 'For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1';
var re = /see (chapter \d+(\.\d)*)/i;
var found = str.match(re);

console.log(found); // null
```

---

As another option, from within a browser, you could pass a selector that doesn't match any elements to the [`.querySelector()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). It too will return null if it doesn't find any matches. To be sure that the element doesn't exist (and will return `null`), you can perform the `querySelector` function on an element that you have created for this purpose:

```
var emptyElement = document.createElement("span");
var element = emptyElement.querySelector("#an-id-that-doesnt-exist");
console.log(element) // null
```

Comment: Strictly speaking :`document.querySelector('does not exist'),` , you never know.... Also won't work in node

Comment: @RoyiNamir - yes thats true - you won't be able to 100% know if an element doesn't exist.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - as for not knowing if the element exists, you could also do the `querySelector` on something you created - that way you can 100% know it will not match anything.